# Problem with reading values from an analog accelorometer

Tags: impedance, impedance-matching, teensy

I have a Teensy 3.2 MCU ([datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/K20P64M72SF1.pdf)) hooked up to an ADXL326 **analog** accelorometer breakout board ([datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL326.pdf)). Visual examination of the board reveals a few SMD capacitors, which are 0.1uF.

I have successfully used a scale value to convert a value to a G value using advice from the manufacturer's forum. For example, when the accelorometer has no force on an axis, it will read 0G. When I apply gravity force, it will change to a ridiculous value like 7G. When the force is removed, it will not go back to 0G -- it will go to a random value from -4G to 4G.

Research has revealed that the accelorometer has an impedence of 32kOhms. See the below image for details on the MCU impedence:

[image]

Is there anyway to **reliably** go from a analog input to a G value using this setup? This is going to be used in a vehicle for data recording during impacts. I have spent $18 on this analog accelorometer, and would not like to purchase a digital accelorometer unless absolutely necessary.

Disclaimer: The truth is, I have no clue what any of this impedance stuff means. I just determined this was the most likely issue from [here.](https://ez.analog.com/thread/73343) They stated that the likely cause is difference in impedance combined with interference from the MCU clock(s). I am not an electronics engineer, I am a software engineer with some basic electronics experience.

Comment: Please post a schematic, you can do this by pressing the schematic button and using the tool when posting or editing questions.

Answer (score 2):

The output impedance of 32 kohm can be a significant problem when attached to the ADC input on the MCU. Table 24 entitled "16-bit ADC operating conditions" states that the input impedance is typically 2 kohm and this will screw up any measurement from a source that has an output impedance of 32 kohm.

You might get away with a parallel capacitor - the sensor data sheet specifies there must be a minimum of 4.7 nF on the sensor output so have you done this? Alternatively you might need an op-amp buffer.

The table in the question suggests that you might be using a PGA in front of the ADC - please confirm that you have enabled this because it makes things easier but you will still need a 4.7 nF capacitor and normal decoupling across the power rails.

Reading further down the PGA table suggests that the analogue source impedance should be typically 100 ohm and this is way lower than what the ADI device is. I think a buffer might be a good idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, a PGA? Pin grid array?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using a breakout board. Visual examination of the board reveals a few SMD capacitors, which are 0.1uF.

Comment: @Saustin "PGA" as mentioned in your table a la \$R_{PGAD}\$. PGA stands for programmable gain amplifier. I believe you can enable this in the teensy. A bunch of 0.1uF capacitors somewhat in the vicinity of the device does not mean that there is a capacitor on the sensor output.

Comment: Amazing, I had no clue such device existed (so no, it is not enabled. I thought the table was the actual input impedance of the device.) Will this save a lot of headache? Should I enable the 64 gain one, or would you recommend to just cut straight to an op amp? And I will look into using a capacitor on the input.

Comment: You will likely get the same problem with both - read the relevant sections - they both suggest source impedance should be less than 100 ohm. I'd be thinking about an opamp like the OPA333 - it should be able to drive the input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Impedance will be a problem as well as DC offset and sampling range.

From the documents you linked, the Teensy wants the impedances on its inputs to be below 5K.

The ADXL326 has 32K resistors on its outputs, so you won't meet the Teensy's requirements just connecting the two together.

You will need to buffer the outputs from the ADXL326 before sending them to the Teensy.

Using a capactor to ground from each output from the ADXL326 might help.  If they are large enough, and you don't need to detect fast changes in acceleration.  The 32K internal resistance and the external capacitor makes a low pass filter as well as lowering the impedance.  The cutoff of the filter can be calculated using equations from the datasheet for the ADXL326.

You may find that isn't enough for proper operation.

In that case, you will need to look into buffering.  That would be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Nwkl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I didn't give a type for the amp because you'll have to determine which you can use/need to use.

You'll need to find a rail to rail op-amp that can run on your voltage rails (3.6V) There are a lot of details involved that can make the choice difficult.  I'd suggest looking around and picking one, then asking here if ithe one you've selected is a good choice.  Be sure to think about such details as precision and sampling rate, and how often you really need to read the acceleration (bandwidth, in other words.)

---

Once you get reliable measurements from the ADXL326, you should be able to use the gain settings, ADC values, and the reference voltage to calculate the acceleration.

Comment: First, thanks for the detailed response. Is the capacitor you mention to be used as a decoupling capacitor? If so, does it matter where this is positioned on the circuit? (i.e. between data jumper cable and MCU input?) Additionally, what is the purpose of determining the cutoff, and where would I use this information?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using a breakout board. Visual examination of the board reveals a few SMD capacitors, which are 0.1uF.

Comment: No, this is not a decoupling capacitor.  These are three capacitors that go from Xout, Yout, Zout to ground.  They are intended to form a low pass filter to reduce noise on the outputs.  Page 11 of the datasheet tells you about them.  (Sectio: Setting the Bandwidth)

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it sounds like it's defective... the output should give always the instant (after low-pass filter) value of the acceleration experienced by the chip, independently from the values previously sensed!

You should:

- know or measure the Vcc provided to the accelerometer and ensure you have little noise on it;
- read the voltage V_pin from the output pin of the IC;
- acceleration=(V_pin - Vcc_accelerometer/2)*max_g

max_g = 16 in your case.

Do not expect a perfect 0g when acceleration is removed, since the Teensy has some noise in the ADC pins.